# Adding an event handler for MapPolygon in Bing Map for Windows Store

Tags: c#, windows, events

I try adding an event handler for a MapPolygon item in `Bing.Map` in a Windows 8.1 store  app and I simply can't find anything on the web. It seems like `Bing.Map` shapes are very limited (e.g MapPolygon only has 3 Properties).

Does anyone know how to trigger an event when the user enters the area of the polygon/ or clicks?

```
        myMap.Credentials = "---";
        myMap.ZoomLevel = 9.5;
        myMap.Center = new Bing.Maps.Location(35.1,33.3);
        myMap.ShowNavigationBar = false;
        myMap.MapType = Bing.Maps.MapType.Aerial;
        //lat 35.34028
        //long -33.31917

        MapShapeLayer shapeLayer = new MapShapeLayer();
        MapPolygon polygon = new MapPolygon();

        //Kyrenia
        polygon.Locations = new LocationCollection() { 
            new Location(35.35028, 33.30917),
            new Location(35.35028, 33.32917),
            new Location(35.33028, 33.32917),
            new Location(35.33028, 33.30917)
            };
        polygon.FillColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Maroon;
        shapeLayer.Shapes.Add(polygon);
        myMap.ShapeLayers.Add(shapeLayer);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the pushpins that works the same with the MapPolygons

```
    private void initMap()
    {
        myMap.Credentials = "---";
        myMap.ZoomLevel = 9.5;
        myMap.Center = new Bing.Maps.Location(35.1,33.3);
        myMap.ShowNavigationBar = false;
        myMap.MapType = Bing.Maps.MapType.Aerial;

        Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
        MapLayer.SetPosition(pushpin, new Location(35.34028, 33.31917));
        myMap.Children.Add(pushpin);
        pushpin.Tapped += pushpin_Tapped;
    }

    void pushpin_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Pushpin tmp = (Pushpin)sender;
        tmp.Text = "ABC";
    }
```